# What is a definition for ‘third-party-curious’?

Tags: meaning

I came across this [NY Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/10/05/opinion/third-party-politics-andrew-yang-david-jolly.html):

"Are You ‘third-party-curious’? Andrew Yang and David Jolly Would Like a Word."

I can't explain to myself what is a third-party-curious

Comment: It's a one-off joke.  There is no "definition".  It's a unique usage, a pun.

Answer (score 23):

"-curious" in this sense originated as a modifier for sexual orientations. It means that you're not saying you fully agree or are committed to something, but that you are willing to explore it — learn more, try it out, and so on.

> She may not be bisexual, but she's bi-curious.

To use it in this way for "third party" (i.e, not Democrats or Republicans) is tongue-in-cheek because it suggests that there's something a little risque and brave about exploring a non-traditional option.

Comment: Mostly only makes sense from a US perspective, as most other democracies have more than 2 viable political parties.  And non-democracies generally just have 1.